# Method Resolution Order (MRO) in Python: super multiple inheritance

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

I got the following example code. I understand that the code is falling since `super(A, self).__init__(attr_base1, attr_base2)` is calling the `__init__` of `B(Base)`, but I don't really understand why. Since I put `A` in `super(A, self)`, I thought that it should search for the parent class starting from `A`. What should I do if I want A.**init**(self, attr1, "b1", "b2") to call in super for the `Base` `__init__`?

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, attr_base1, attr_base2):
        self.attr_base1 = attr_base1
        self.attr_base2 = attr_base2

    def foo(self):
        print ('A.foo()')

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, attr, attr_base1, attr_base2):
        super(A, self).__init__(attr_base1, attr_base2)
        self.attr1 = attr

class B(Base):
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr2 = attr

    def foo(self):
        print ('B.foo()')

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        A.__init__(self, attr1, "b1", "b2")
        A.__init__(self, attr2)

c = C(1, 2)
```

Comment: That's how the `super` magic works.  Calling `super(A...` within the `C` initialization sequence goes back to the initialization order for `C`, and in order, `B` follows `A`, so it calls `B.__init__` next.  If you want to control the order by hand, then don't user `super` here.

Comment: @TimRoberts, When writing `super`  without any arguments, I understand why this is working like this, but when you are stating in the passed argument the class you are willing to start searching the method, it seems odd.

Comment: You state the one to start _above_, usually the class you're writing it in.

Comment: You virtually never need to pass explicit arguments to `super`. Python 3 added "default" arguments to `super` precisely because those are nearly always the arguments you want to pass.

Comment: Right.  It is the OBJECT that has a resolution order.  When you say `super(A...)`,  you're not saying "go call the parent(s) of class A".  You're saying "go call the next parent of this object, starting after class A".

Comment: @TimRoberts Meaning going to the next class in the MRO of OBJECT, right? So what would be a practical usage of this argument type (like A in my example) in super?

Comment: @chepner said it.  The argument serves no purpose.  It was there when `super` was first introduced, but it was shortly thereafter modified to make the arguments unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would redefine all three classes to make them work better in a cooperative multiple-inheritance hierarchy. (See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for more information about the design choices made here.)

Some general rules for `__init__`:

1. Accept arbitrary keyword arguments.
2. Always call `super().__init__` with the extra keyword arguments,
   even if you are only statically inheriting from `object`.
3. Use keyword-only parameters with `__init__`
4. Make sure parameter names are distinct across the classes.
5. If you try to inherit base classes that violate any of the above rules, you may need to write adaptor classes that wrap the offending classes and inherit from the adaptors instead.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, *, attr_base1, attr_base2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.attr_base1 = attr_base1
        self.attr_base2 = attr_base2

    def foo(self):
        print ('A.foo()')


class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, *, a_attr, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.attr1 = a_attr


class B(Base):
    def __init__(self, *, b_attr, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.attr2 = b_attr

    def foo(self):
        print ('B.foo()')


class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Override any explicitly passed values.
        kwargs["attr_base1"] = "b1"
        kwargs["attr_base2"] = "b2"

        super().__init__(**kwargs)


c = C(a_attr=1, b_attr=2)
```

In this example,

1. `C.__init__` is responsible for hard-coding the base-class attributes before delegating the actual initialization to `A.__init__`.
2. `A.__init__` is responsible for extracting `a_attr` from the keyword arguments and initializing the attribute `attr1` before delegating the rest of the initialization to `B.__init__`.
3. `B.__init__` is responsible for extracting `b_attr` fro the keyword arguments and initializing the attribute `attr2` before delegating the rest of the initialization to `Base.__init__`.
4. `Base.__init__` is responsible for extracting `attr_base1` and `attr_base2` from the keyword arguments, and initializing the attributes `attr_base1` and `attr_base2` before delegating the rest of the initialization to `object.__init__`.
5. `object.__init__` doesn't really do anything except produce an exception if any "unclaimed" keyword arguments get passed to it.

Comment: I accept the answer, but I think this adds an undesirable complexity to the code. Since `B(Base)` is like an abstract class for me, then I chose to remove its `__init__`, and add the attributions as properties (with setters as well). Thank you